# Angular Material: date picker, missing theme?

Tags: angularjs

I got some trouble integrating the [Angular Material date picker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) in my application:

[image: Angular Material date picker: missing theme]

Looking at the diff between my local version and the demo version, I noticed that I don't have any `<style md-theme-style>` element in my head. What am I missing? :)

I added the `ngMaterial` dependency to my app, and included the `./node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.scss` file through Webpack. Moreover, I didn't override the `$mdThemingProvider` configuration.

Any clue? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the latest release of angular-material.min.js to your project:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0-rc1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I had the same issue you were having all day and after reading your question, I decided to also compare my project with the demo version, which brought me to the solution, so thank you!

Comment: Forgotten to valid this one. Thanks, indeed, it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's bug in version 0.11.4 [See here](https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.4/demo/datepicker)

It works fine in verion 0.11.3. [See here](https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.3/demo/datepicker)

It also works fine in version 1.0.0-rc7 [See here](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.0-rc7/demo/datepicker)

Just choose a different version.